# Matlab's cannot call Python code that imports statsmodels

Tags: python, matlab

This question concerns Matlab 2014b, Python 3.4 and Mac OS 10.10.

I have the following Python file `tmp.py`:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
import numpy as np
def generate_AR_time_series():
    arparams = np.array([-0.8])
    maparams = np.array([])
    ar = np.r_[1, -arparams]
    ma = np.r_[1, maparams]
    arma_process = ArmaProcess(ar, ma)
    return arma_process.generate_sample(100)
```

I want to call generate_AR_time_series from Matlab so I used:

```
py.tmp.generate_AR_time_series()
```

which gave a vague error message

```
Undefined variable "py" or class "py.tmp.generate_AR_time_series".
```

To look into the problem further, I tried

```
tmp = py.eval('__import__(''tmp'')', struct);
which gave me a detailed but still obscured error message:

Python Error:
dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so, 2): Symbol
not found: __gfortran_stop_numeric_f08
  Referenced from: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.3.dylib
 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
```

I can call the function within Python just fine, so I guess the problem is with Matlab. From the detailed message, it seems that the problem lies in something is expected in the Matlab installation path, but of course Matlab installation path does not contain those things since they are third-party libraries for Python.

How to solve this problem?

**Edit 1**:
`libgfortran.3.dylib` can be found in a lot of places:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.3.dylib
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.3.dylib
/opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.3.dylib
/opt/local/lib/gcc49/libgfortran.3.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgfortran.3.dylib
/Users/wdg/Documents/MATLAB/mcode/nativelibs/macosx/bin/libgfortran.3.dylib
```

Comment: Could you check if the `libgfortran.3.dylib` also exists a second time on your pc? Seems matlab brings the wrong version of it.

Comment: @Daniel, what do you mean by "exists a second time"?

Comment: Do you find this lib a second time on your hard drive? For example in the numpy directory?

Comment: @Daniel, Yes. I found the lib in more than 2 places. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
setenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/usr/local/bin/');
```

Comment: You might add a bit of an explanation

Answer (score 0):

For me, using the `setenv` approach from within MATLAB did not work. Also, MATLAB modifies the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable during startup to include necessary libraries.

First, you have to make sure which version of `gfortran` `scipy` was linked against: in Terminal.app, enter `otool -L /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so` and look for '`libgfortran`' in the output.

It worked for me to copy `$(MATLABROOT)/bin/.matlab7rc.sh` to my home directory and change the line `LDPATH_PREFIX=''` in the `mac` section (around line 195 in my case) to `LDPATH_PREFIX='/opt/local/lib/gcc49'`, or whatever path to `libgfortran` you found above.
This ensures that `/opt/local/lib/gcc49/libgfortran.3.dylib` is found before the MATLAB version, but leaves other paths intact.